# How to connect RNN at the end of a CNN to use to train video frames?

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, conv-neural-network, recurrent-neural-network

I'm trying to classify a video as image classification thus to use the frames as the classified method. But i have no idea how to code it out. 
I'm using Inception ResNet as my CNN but don't know any RNN or how to use them.

Comment: Please share more insight on your current architecture: What you have so far, a schematic of what you are trying to achieve, and maybe some research you have done looking into this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is ML_machine, here is what I wanted to show you,
this is an implementation of a CNN to classify the mnist data, it is not mine and come from [here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/examples/mnist_cnn.py)

```
import keras
from keras.datasets import mnist
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Flatten
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras import backend as K

batch_size = 128
num_classes = 10
epochs = 12

# input image dimensions
img_rows, img_cols = 28, 28

# the data, split between train and test sets
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()

if K.image_data_format() == 'channels_first':
    x_train = x_train.reshape(x_train.shape[0], 1, img_rows, img_cols)
    x_test = x_test.reshape(x_test.shape[0], 1, img_rows, img_cols)
    input_shape = (1, img_rows, img_cols)
else:
    x_train = x_train.reshape(x_train.shape[0], img_rows, img_cols, 1)
    x_test = x_test.reshape(x_test.shape[0], img_rows, img_cols, 1)
    input_shape = (img_rows, img_cols, 1)

x_train = x_train.astype('float32')
x_test = x_test.astype('float32')
x_train /= 255
x_test /= 255
print('x_train shape:', x_train.shape)
print(x_train.shape[0], 'train samples')
print(x_test.shape[0], 'test samples')

# convert class vectors to binary class matrices
y_train = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_train, num_classes)
y_test = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_test, num_classes)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3),
                 activation='relu',
                 input_shape=input_shape))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss=keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy,
              optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adadelta(),
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(x_train, y_train,
          batch_size=batch_size,
          epochs=epochs,
          verbose=1,
          validation_data=(x_test, y_test))
score = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test, verbose=0)
print('Test loss:', score[0])
print('Test accuracy:', score[1])
```

to convert this CNN followed by a fully connected layer into a CNN into RNN, simply change the line

```
model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))
```

into

```
model.add(SimpleRNN(num_classes, activation='softmax'))
```

(of course you need to import it)

you might have to change the input dimension of your network and/or TimeDistribute the whole CNN part, I had trouble in some version of tensorflow and others not

EDIT:

I encountered some problem on my own with the code I gave you, it is harder than I thought because of the dimensions to end a CNN network with a recurrent one, here is how I managed to do it:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=in_shape))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
# NO MORE POOLING
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
# Reshape with the first argument being the number of filter in your last conv layer
model.add(Reshape((64, -1)))
# Just write this Permute after, its complicated why
model.add(Permute((2, 1)))
# it can also be an LSTM
model.add(SimpleRNN(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))
```

EDIT2, dummy example of a simple fully connected NN in keras:

```
trng_input = np.random.uniform(size=(1000, 4))
trng_output = np.column_stack([np.sin(trng_input).sum(axis=1), np.cos(trng_input).sum(axis=1)])

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(6, input_shape=trng_input.shape, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(2, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='MSE', optimizer=keras.optimizer.Adam(), metrics=['accuracy'])
```